# How to find PDF of a random variable when it is squared and multiplied by constant?

Tags: probability-distributions, density-function, cumulative-distribution-functions

I am getting confused in the following situation. Say we have a random variable $X$ whose PDF is known to us.

Now how to find the PDF of another random variable say $Y$, which is related to $X$ as

$Y = AX^2$ ----(1)

Thus my query is how to find PDF of $Y$ when random variable $X$ is squared and multiplied by constant.

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Comment: This is a [change of variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Function_of_random_variables_and_change_of_variables_in_the_probability_density_function), and theoretically not difficult to deal with either directly or using the CDF.  If $X$ can take positive and negative values, then you may need a bit of addition.

Comment: Thanks sir for your answer....will try with these approach....